# Table partitioning using the Kafka Connect GCP BigQuery Sink Connector

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Folks,

I am using the confluent connector for data transmission in BigQuery. For each event I have I created an avro schema that will be interpreted in BigQuery. Is it possible to define any event field as table partition?

It is currently using the _PARTITIONTIME hidden field but I need it to be a field for actual event to make it easier to handle duplicates for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can [partition by one of your Date or Timestamp columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#top_of_page). Also, there's a Beta feature for [integer range partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions#top_of_page) to partition by integer columns.

Comment: @Tiaquetzal this i know, i want to understand where i create the partition inside sink configuration process between kafka and bigquery (confluent connector), is it in avro schema? If so, do you have any examples you can share?

Comment: @FelipeFB There doesn't seem to be an option to specify the schema directly from the connector. In the [source code](https://github.com/wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery/blob/master/kcbq-connector/src/main/java/com/wepay/kafka/connect/bigquery/SchemaManager.java) you can see that the definition of Partition is not variable; however, you can create the table on your BigQuery dataset as required, and just use the connector to stream.

Comment: I have done a test and unfortunately the connector cannot transmit the event to the table created.

Comment: Could you describe what you did? Did you try creating first the tables? What error(s) did you see?